# Fragments not updating ViewPageAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Currently, I am working on a project, where I have implemented a viewPager and a bottom navigation view to change fragments. Also I can swipe left and right to change fragments.

When I click on an item on the navigation view, the fragment changes to the attached fragment. My bottom navigation view is set up like this:

[image]

The issue is difficult to explain, but this is my attempt:

The fragments only updates AFTER I've been at the fragment "Home".

This means that, when clicking on "Oversigt" after I've been at "Home", the fragment "Oversigt" will update it's views. But if I'm not in "Home", and in one of the other Fragments, and I click on a fragment "Oversigt". Then "Oversigt" won't update it's views.

My MainActivity:

```
public void setViewPager(int fragmentNumber) {

    mPager.setCurrentItem( fragmentNumber );

}

public void enableViewPagerSwitch() {

    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener( new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                prevMenuItem.setChecked( false );
            } else {
                mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem( 0 ).setChecked( false );
                navigationView.getMenu().getItem( 0 ).setChecked( false );

            }
            Log.d( "page", "onPageSelected: " + position );

            mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem( position ).setChecked( true );
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem( position ).setChecked( true );

            prevMenuItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem( position );
            prevMenuItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem( position );

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    } );

    setupViewPager( mPager );

}


public void bot_Navigation() {

    mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById( R.id.nav_bot );

    botNavHelper.disableShiftMode( mBottomNav );

    mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener( new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.bot_startside:
                    setViewPager( 0 );
                    break;

                case R.id.bot_datatabel:
                    setViewPager( 1 );
                    break;

                case R.id.bot_sensorOversigt:
                    setViewPager( 2 );
                    break;

                case R.id.bot_kontakt:
                    setViewPager( 3 );
                    break;

                case R.id.bot_logUd:
                    setViewPager( 4 );
                    alertDialog();
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    } );

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    onCreate2();

    bot_Navigation();

}

protected void onCreate2() {

    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
    setSupportActionBar( toolbar );

    TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById( R.id.toolbartitle );

    mTitle.setText( toolbar.getTitle() );

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled( false );

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById( R.id.flMain );

    enableViewPagerSwitch();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close );
    drawer.addDrawerListener( toggle );
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById( R.id.nav_view );
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener( this );

    navigationView.setCheckedItem( R.id.nav_startside );

}
```

This is the ViewPageAdapter:

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super( fm );
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragmentList.add( fragment );
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get( position );
}

@Override
public int getCount() { return mFragmentList.size(); }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
public abstract class SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements Serializable {
    // Sparse array to keep track of registered fragments in memory
    private SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    public SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Register the fragment when the item is instantiated
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    // Unregister when the item is inactive
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    // Returns the fragment for the position (if instantiated)
    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
```

and depending on where you are creating these fragments, you might want to try using `getChildFragmentManager` instead. Another approach is to use the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you explain how?

Comment: This class overrides the instantiateItem() method and caches any created fragments internally. Your pagerAdapter can then extend the SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter. Then in your main fragment u can user `myPagerAdapter.instantiateItem();` to create the individual fragments

Comment: Allright, so far have I extended my PageAdapter to the SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter. Now i'm not sure where to implement: mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(); -> Should i implement in my navigation view?

Comment: Should probably be in the view which is going to display it. So wherever you were creating the fragments, this can replace it there